# mysql query where not with Hierarchical tables

Tags: mysql

So basically I'm joining 3 tables together. The main table is recipe, then it goes to ingredients list then ingredient.

So I need to have a query which has only recipes which contain NO  chicken. The problem I am having is that because recipes have many ingredients when I use where != that just removes the ingredients with that meat but leaves the others.....how can i account for the multiple ingredients.

```
select Recipe.name as "No chicken"  from Recipe inner join IngredientList on Recipe.recipeId=IngredientList.recipeId inner join Ingredients on IngredientList.IngredientId=Ingredients.ingredientId where type!="chcicken" group by Recipe.name;
```

Comment: Also it seems if I just want chicken...so type="chicken" and that yields only chicken recipes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original statement has a `GROUP BY` with no aggregate function.  That doesn't make sense.  It should be an `ORDER BY` if you're trying to sort.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT `Recipe`.`name` AS "No chicken"
FROM `Recipe`
WHERE `Recipe`.`RecipeId` NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `IngredientList`.`RecipeId` AS `RecipeID`
    FROM `IngredientList`
        INNER JOIN `Ingredients` ON `IngredientList`.`IngredientId` = `Ingredients`.`IngredientId`
    WHERE `Ingredients`.`Type` = 'chicken'
)
ORDER BY `Recipe`.`name`
```

Depending on your schema, you may need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the main select statement if you're getting duplicate recipe names.

Answer (score 1):

The above have some typos, but Amirshk has a logically correct answer.

However, I recommend one avoid the IN() and NOT IN() clauses in MySQL as they are very, very slow on a set of tables as big as a large recipe database would get.  IN and NOT IN can be re-written as joins to cut the runtime to 1/100th the time in MySQL 5.0.  Even with MySQL 5.5's great improvements, the equivalent JOIN query benchmarks 1/5th the time on large tables.

Here is the revised query:

```
SELECT
Recipe.name AS "No Chicken"
FROM Recipe LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT IngredientList.recipeId, Ingredients.ingredientId
    FROM IngredientList JOIN Ingredients USING (IngredientId)
    WHERE Ingredients.type = 'chicken'
    ) WithChicken
    ON Recipe.recipeId = WithChicken.recipeId
WHERE WithChicken.recipeId IS NULL;
```

This is pretty obtuse, so here is simplified SQL that provides the key concept of the NOT IN(...) equivalent exclusion join:

```
SELECT whatever FROM x
WHERE x.id NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM y
};
```

becomes

```
SELECT whatever FROM x
LEFT JOIN y ON x.id = y.id
WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner query to filter recipes with chicken, then select all the recipes without them.

As so:

```
select
    Recipe.name as "No chicken"
    from Recipe
        inner join IngredientList on Recipe.recipeId=IngredientList.recipeId
        inner join Ingredients on IngredientList.IngredientId=Ingredients.ingredientId
    where Recipe.recipeId NOT IN (
        select
        Recipe.recipeId
        from Recipe
            inner join IngredientList on Recipe.recipeId=IngredientList.recipeId
            inner join Ingredients on IngredientList.IngredientId=Ingredients.ingredientId
            type ="chcicken" group by Recipe.recipeId)
```